# List comprehension and matrix partitioning

Tags: python, list, matrix, list-comprehension, partitioning

So I have

```
mat = [[a_11, a_12, ... , a_1n],
       [a_21, a_22, ... , a_2n],
       ...
       [a_n1, a_n2, ... , a_nn]]
```

and I want to make a `k * k` sized **square** submatrix from this with values sampled from `mat` (1 < k < n), but if `mat[x][y]` is selected then I want `mat[y][x]` also be selected.

To clarify:

```
submat = [[mat[x_1][x_1], mat[x_1][x_2], ... mat[x_1][x_k]],
          [mat[x_2][x_1], mat[x_2][x_2], ... mat[x_2][x_k]],     
          ...
          [mat[x_k][x_1], mat[x_k][x_2], ... mat[x_k][x_k]]]
```

with x_1, x_2, ... , x_k randomly chosen and not identical
(x_1, x_2, ... , x_k are integers which range from 0 to n).

For example, with this array (`n = 4`)

```
mat = [[1, 5, 7, 0],
       [2, 4, 3, 1],
       [4, 9, 8, 1],
       [1, 0, 9, 3]]
```

with `k = 2` I want sampled results like:

```py
[[1, 1],
 [0, 2]]
```

---

I tried

```
ordDet = [0, 1, 2, 3]
random.shuffle(ordDet)

submat = [
         [mat[ordDet[0]][ordDet[0]], mat[ordDet[0]][ordDet[1]]],
         [mat[ordDet[1]][ordDet[0]], mat[ordDet[1]][ordDet[1]]]
                                                              ]
```

but is there a way to do this using list comprehension?

Comment: will the submat always have the same size? 2x2

Comment: Ah just one thing - binding name as `ord` isn't a good idea! You just shadowed built-in function `ord()`! Check out this [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=ord#ord)!

Comment: @jupiterbjy yeah I originally used ordDet instead of ord, editing it right now

Comment: How do `ordDet` and `submat` change for larger matrices?

Comment: @tstx nah, mat could be something like 28x28 and submat 7x7. I'm just testing this with 2x2

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal ok so one example mat is a 28x28 matrix, ordDet = [0, 1, 2, ..., 27]
and submat could be any size between 2 and 27

Comment: Mind including how matrix could be shaped like, possibly with some sample matrix, would ya ;) That will help you get your answers more quickly!

Comment: @BilqizGairbekov So the resulting matrix is always square? And do the resulting dimensions stem from `ordDet`? Right now it's unclear what the pattern for your submatrix is.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal I edited my question and hope it makes more sense... I realized my wording and formatting were pretty unclear.

Comment: Oh seems like what you want is to *"Sample `k x k` data randomly from Matrix **without** overlapping, and shape it as `k x k` Matrix"* - is this correct?

Comment: @jupiterbjy Correct!

Comment: Ermm... I don't think I got the concept right still, seems like you only want to sample 1 axis index and use it for both X and Y rather than sampling both? I think I edited your question in wrong direction in that case

Comment: @jupiterbjy I didn't fully understand 'sample 1 axis index and use it for both X and Y rather than sampling both', but tstx' answer worked for me. For example, if mat[2][1] were sampled, I'd always want mat[1][2] to be sampled too (symmetrical is the right word I think).

Comment: Got it! Hope that's the final edit, phew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you?
Just define 'SUBMAT_WIDTH' for the submatrix

This would work only if the input and output matrixes are square

```
import random

mat = [[0, 5, 3, 1],
       [2, 0, 4, 2],
       [3, 4, 0, 3],
       [2, 3, 5, 0]]
#define submat width
SUBMAT_WIDTH = 3

#create list of all indexes and shuffle it
randomindexes=[x for x in range(len(mat))]
random.shuffle(randomindexes)

#slice random indexes
randomindexes = randomindexes[:SUBMAT_WIDTH]


sub_mat = [[mat[x][y] for y in randomindexes ] for x in randomindexes]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Not in-line with updated question

Leaving this answer for someone who is looking for sampling without condition.

---

Now the question is clarified, here's what you need to keep in mind: `random.shuffle` is not quite ideal.

From python [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

> *random.shuffle(x)*
>
> Shuffle the sequence x **in place**.
>
> To shuffle an immutable sequence and return a new shuffled list, use sample(x, k=len(x)) instead.
>
> Note that **even for small len(x)**, the total number of permutations of x **can quickly grow larger than the period of most random number generators**.
>
> This implies that **most permutations of a long sequence can never be generated**. For example, a sequence of length 2080 is the largest that can fit within the period of the Mersenne Twister random number generator.

*In-Place* operations means that this will be bit slower - altho my testing showed not more than a margin of error - and later parts explains that this operation may not give you the proper even distribution you expected;

Instead, as suggested in docs, use `random.sample` instead:

> *random.sample(population, k, *, counts=None)*
>
> Return a k length list of **unique elements** chosen from the population sequence. Used for random sampling without replacement.
>
> Returns a new list containing elements from the population while **leaving the original population unchanged**.
>
> **If the population contains repeats**, then **each occurrence is a possible selection** in the sample.

This explains that this is not `In-Place` operation, and also consider duplicates as different candidates.

```py
import random
import itertools

# some arbitrary matrix size
mat_n = 9
mat = [list(range(start * mat_n, (start + 1) * mat_n)) for start in range(mat_n)]

# sample k * k data
k = 5
samples = random.sample(list(itertools.chain(*mat)), k * k)
sampled_2d = [samples[start: start + k] for start in range(0, k * k, k)]

# using numpy for pretty printing, not needed
import numpy as np
print(f"Original:\n{np.array(mat)}\n")
print(f"Sampled:\n{np.array(sampled_2d)}")
```

output:

```
Original:
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17]
 [18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26]
 [27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35]
 [36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44]
 [45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53]
 [54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62]
 [63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71]
 [72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80]]
Sampled:
[[52 30 31 33  6]
 [72 25 29  0 75]
 [ 7 41 37 23 58]
 [65 13 64 10 22]
 [18 71 16 26 42]]
```

---

### Old Answer:

Despite *Zen of Python* states *"Thou shall refuse the temptation to guess"* - but I'll guess what author want is partitioning matrix into 4 sections, like this:

[image]

For that I think one liner ain't worth - technically possible, but should we call a 80+ long unreadable code as one-liner? Nope!

But maybe two will make it much more clear, or 3 if you make it function.

Point of this question is not *How to get random number* and I am pretty sure author knows how to use `random.randint` - so I'll be focusing on matrix partitioning itself.

```py
# some arbitrary matrix size
mat_x, mat_y = (9, 7)
mat = [list(range(start * mat_x, (start + 1) * mat_x)) for start in range(mat_y)]


def part_mat(matrix, row, col):
    """Partition matrix into 4 chunks from (row, col) position.

    Args:
        matrix: Matrix to cut
        row: row cut index
        col: column cut index

    Returns:
        4 Partitioned matrices, ordered from top left & right, bottom left & right
    """

    # split column into top & bottom section & transpose
    upper, lower = list(zip(*matrix[:col])), list(zip(*matrix[col:]))

    # cut row and transpose again
    return [list(zip(*rows)) for rows in (upper[:row], upper[row:], lower[:row], lower[row:])]


# ---

import numpy as np
# pprint.pprint ain't doing its job fine, using numpy for prett printing

print(f"Original Matrix:\n{np.array(mat)}\n")

for sub_mat in part_mat(mat, 3, 4):
    print(np.array(sub_mat))
```

output:

```
Original Matrix:
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17]
 [18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26]
 [27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35]
 [36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44]
 [45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53]
 [54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62]]

[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 9 10 11]
 [18 19 20]
 [27 28 29]]
[[ 3  4  5  6  7  8]
 [12 13 14 15 16 17]
 [21 22 23 24 25 26]
 [30 31 32 33 34 35]]
[[36 37 38]
 [45 46 47]
 [54 55 56]]
[[39 40 41 42 43 44]
 [48 49 50 51 52 53]
 [57 58 59 60 61 62]]
```

Even better is just to use 3rd party libraries though! Like, `pandas`, `numpy`, etc

```py
>>> mat_x, mat_y = (9, 7)
>>> mat = [list(range(start * mat_x, (start + 1) * mat_x)) for start in range(mat_y)]

>>> import numpy as np
>>> np_mat = np.array(mat)

>>> np_mat[:4, :3]
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [18, 19, 20],
       [27, 28, 29]])

>>> np_mat[:4, 3:]
array([[ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])

>>> np_mat[4:, :3]
array([[36, 37, 38],
       [45, 46, 47],
       [54, 55, 56]])

>>> np_mat[4:, 3:]
array([[39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
       [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53],
       [57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the code more generic in order for it to work with arbitrary dimensions, however, (obviously) you need to choose the matrix dimensions of `submat` to be smaller than `mat`. You can add an exception algorithm if you want.

```
import random
import numpy as np


mat = [[0, 5, 3, 1],
       [2, 0, 4, 2],
       [3, 4, 0, 3],
       [2, 3, 5, 0]]



n=len(mat) # rows
m=len(mat[0]) # columns



rows=[i for i in range(n)]
columns=[i for i in range(m)]


random.shuffle(rows)
random.shuffle(columns)

submat_rows = int(input("Enter the no. of submat rows: "))
submat_columns = int(input("Enter the no. of submat columns: "))

submat= np.zeros(shape=(submat_rows, submat_columns))



for i in range(submat_rows):
    adding_rows= [mat[random.choice(rows)][random.choice(columns)] for i in range(submat_columns)]
    submat[i]=adding_rows
```